# Gedit has a transparent background since upgrade to 16.10

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, gedit

Since I upgraded to from 16.04 to 16.10, gedit has strange new "feature": its background is totally transparent.

[image: like here]

Where can this come from ?

Notice I'm using Unity and don't have any specific gnome package installed besides what comes by default.
Notice also that in 16.04 I used the Vivacious theme from ravefinity PPA, but I had to go back to Ambiance as Vivacious was broken in 16.10. Maybe it's related.

[EDIT] changing the 'Fonts and Colors' in gedit to any theme other than default (Kate, Solarized, Oblivion, etc..) solves the issue. So there must be a faulty gtksourview file in my home somewhare, but I can't find it...

Comment: @CelticWarrior any idea how to suppress theme remnants on my user account?

Comment: Perhaps using ppa-purge against the theme PPA to revert all changes.

Comment: I believe the [latest revision](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/838259/3) you made seems to add the "solution" to the question. So, I'll recommend you to kindly add that as answer and remove the solution from the question body. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kulfy actually, the latest edit only provides a workaround, and doesn't allow the use of the default theme, and they confirm that there's still a problem. My answer **IS** the true correct answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem. After much digging, I found that the file **$HOME/.xinputrc** was the cause. I just deleted this file with:

```
rm ~/.xinputrc
```

The contents of the file are:

```
# im-config(8) generated on Tue, 18 Aug 2015 16:56:49 -0700
run_im ibus
im-config signature: fef625e6f3691095fd8f4a2f315e85f7  -
```

After deleting the above file you will need to logout and log back in for changes to take effect (or just reboot).

Comment: @heynnema works for me too, but I don't understand how this is related at all. Do you have any insight on what happens ?

Comment: It has something to do with the "input method", which is something you could set from System Settings in previous versions of Ubuntu. I still don't know why it did what it did to gedit though. Cheers, Al

Comment: reboot after that to make changes update