# Code text box blurs/fails to refresh

Tags: lubuntu, 17.04, gtk

I am trying to use Giggle and gitg on my computer.

Both apps display code from git directories.

Both apps show the following when I scroll:

[image: Blurred/non-refreshed text issue]

Since the apps are from different groups, I suspect an underlying issue with a gtk component, but I haven't been able to find a bug report anywhere and am not even sure where to submit one.

Does anyone know how to resolve this (visual) issue or have a good handle on who to ask about it?

I am running Lubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/838259/gedit-has-a-transparent-background-since-upgrade-to-16-10.  I suspect it's the same bug as for me the transparency was only after switching windows.  The issue otherwise looked like yours and also affected gitg.

Comment: @MartinThornton: That fixed it! Thanks so much!