# Why do I see a current screenshot of my screen everytime I open gedit?

Tags: gedit

When I open my gedit without root, I get this strange glitch as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Gedit interface glitch]

However when I type "sudo gedit" in a terminal it works fine.

My graphics card is a Intel Corporation Iris Graphics 6100 and I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

This is the current output to my gedit settings:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep -i gedit

org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui bottom-panel-visible false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents uint32 5
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui statusbar-visible true
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui show-tabs-mode 'auto'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui side-panel-visible false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui toolbar-visible true
org.gnome.gedit.plugins active-plugins ['filebrowser', 'modelines', 'spell', 'time', 'docinfo']
org.gnome.gedit.state.history-entry search-for-entry ['']
org.gnome.gedit.state.history-entry replace-with-entry ['']
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-syntax-highlighting true
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print margin-bottom 25.0
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-font-numbers-pango 'Sans 8'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-header true
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-line-numbers uint32 0
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-wrap-mode 'word'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print margin-top 15.0
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-font-body-pango 'Monospace 9'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print margin-left 25.0
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print margin-right 25.0
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.print print-font-header-pango 'Sans 11'
org.gnome.shell favorite-apps ['org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'notepadqq.desktop', 'firefox.desktop', 'runescape-oldschool.desktop', 'discord.desktop', 'org.gnome.gedit.desktop']
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.encodings candidate-encodings ['']
org.gnome.gedit.state.window size (644, 352)
org.gnome.gedit.state.window state 43908
org.gnome.gedit.state.window bottom-panel-active-page ''
org.gnome.gedit.state.window bottom-panel-size 140
org.gnome.gedit.state.window side-panel-active-page 'GeditWindowDocumentsPanel'
org.gnome.gedit.state.window side-panel-size 200
org.gnome.desktop.notifications application-children ['org-gnome-software', 'discord', 'org-gnome-nautilus', 'hexchat', 'org-gnome-dejadup', 'gnome-control-center', 'libreoffice-writer', 'firefox', 'apport-gtk', 'org-gnome-gedit', 'wireshark', 'org-gnome-terminal', 'gnome-network-panel', 'notepadqq', 'org-gnome-totem', 'eog', 'shotwell', 'virtualbox', 'thunderbird', 'update-manager', 'org-gnome-cheese', 'indicator-stickynotes']
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time selected-format '%c'
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time prompt-type 'prompt-selected-format'
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time custom-format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.nautilus confirm-trash true
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser.nautilus click-policy 'double'
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser binary-patterns ['*.la', '*.lo']
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser filter-mode ['hide-hidden', 'hide-binary']
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser filter-pattern ''
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser tree-view true
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser open-at-first-doc true
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser virtual-root 'file:///etc/modprobe.d'
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser enable-remote false
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.filebrowser root 'file:///'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor wrap-mode 'word'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor display-right-margin false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor highlight-current-line false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor search-highlighting true
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor display-overview-map false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor create-backup-copy false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor auto-save false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor restore-cursor-position true
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor bracket-matching false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor scheme 'classic'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor display-line-numbers true
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor editor-font 'Monospace 12'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor insert-spaces false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor right-margin-position uint32 80
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor tabs-size uint32 8
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor background-pattern 'none'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor use-default-font true
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor ensure-trailing-newline true
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor wrap-last-split-mode 'word'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor smart-home-end 'after'
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor auto-indent false
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor max-undo-actions 2000
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor auto-save-interval uint32 10
org.gnome.gedit.preferences.editor syntax-highlighting true
org.gnome.gedit.state.file-filter filter-id 0
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.pythonconsole command-color '#314e6c'
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.pythonconsole use-system-font true
org.gnome.gedit.plugio fixns.pythonconsole error-color '#990000'
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.pythonconsole font 'Monospace 10'
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.externaltools use-system-font true
org.gnome.gedit.plugins.externaltools font 'Monospace 10'
```

Update: I just attempted to try fix this issue by myself and just done the following steps:

- Logged out of current session.
- Select a user to login as.
- Clicked the gear icon and switched to ubuntu on wayland (I was using ubuntu)

This has fixed my issue and gedit now works fine.

Comment: Looks like probably a bug in gtk+ or the graphics drivers.

Comment: Hi, It seems to work on ubuntu on wayland but not on ubuntu.

Comment: If you find a solution you're happy with, post it as an answer, and mark the checkmark at left to show it worked. The objective of this site is to compile a database of answers which work, so providing your own answer to others is encouraged. You may also report it as a bug after searching for it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution: just delete ~/.xinputrc

Found in [Gedit has a transparent background since upgrade to 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838259/gedit-has-a-transparent-background-since-upgrade-to-16-10/840073#840073)

Comment: As mentioned in the linked post, logout is not enough to apply this change. Need to reboot.