# My text editor has the display problem, How to fix it?

Tags: 18.04, gedit

My text editor has the display problem.
How to fix?

[image: text editor problem, someone can help me? Thanks!!]

Comment: Is it only with `gedit`? did you try other editors (e.g. `geany`). And could you please edit your question and add information on your hardware, especially graphics.

Comment: @pLumo mine has same problem but I'm using NVIDIA driver metapack from nvidia-driver-435 (properitary, tested) . VGA: GTX-1050, CPU: i7 7600, RAM 8GB 2133

Comment: If you changed your input method recently, you might try to use this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/838259/gedit-has-a-transparent-background-since-upgrade-to-16-10/840073#840073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be some mess (bug) with the custom configuration of the editor.
Please try to remove ./.config/gedit from your home folder:

```
rm -rf ./.config/gedit
```

And start gedit again.
You may backup "./.config/gedit" before deleting it!

Comment: mine has same problem but not fixed with `rm -rf ./.config/gedit` and I have the same issue in calculator as well. I should mention that I'm using **NVIDIA driver metapack from nvidia-driver-435 (properitary, tested)**