# (18.04) Gedit and Calculator with a transparent background for more than an year and I can't fix it

Tags: themes, ibus, input

For more than an year Gedit and Calculator are unusable due to having a transparent background. Example: [gedit transparent background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLN41.png)

I have tried the suggestions here: [Gedit has a transparent background since upgrade to 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838259/gedit-has-a-transparent-background-since-upgrade-to-16-10)

Here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1760818

And here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1620806

Deleting xim, changing input method, uninstalling ubuntu-desktop and im-config... nothing worked except for changing the theme to "Adwaita", which is a workaround, not the real solution.

Whenever I change my input method, it defaults back to XIM whenever I login again. I don't understand why this is happening.

Do I have any choice other than formatting?

Comment: Can you try with a newly created user? (BTW, do you plan to upgrade to 20.04?)

Comment: Are they installed as snaps?

Comment: I created a new user and the issue does not appear on the new user. No plans to upgrade to 20.04 in the near future.

I had two calculators, one as snap and another as a regular app. Both showed the problem. I uninstalled both and installed only the regular one (apt), but the problem persisted. Gedit is installed as a regular app.